# Fastlane build not executed on VSTS CI

Tags: xcode, continuous-integration, azure-devops, fastlane, fastlane-gym

I'm trying to automate my build proces via VSTS Continuous Integration. VSTS comes with a task that can build the project for me but I'm already using fastlane locally so I prefer to use this on the build server as well. I created a shell script that executes fastlane and publishes the artifacts. The command I use to build is:

```
fastlane gym \
-p "app.xcodeproj" \
-n "app.ipa" \
-c true \
-q "Debug" \
-j "development" \
-i "iPhone Developer: Firstname Lastname" \
-z false \
--verbose
```

And this produces the following command:

```
xcodebuild \
-scheme app-Debug \        
-project app.xcodeproj \
-configuration Debug  \
-destination \
-archivePath /Users/vsts/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2018-04-16/app-debug\ 2018-04-16\ 09.03.03.xcarchive \
clean \
archive \
CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY=iPhone\ Developer:\ Firstname\ Lastname \ tee /Users/vsts/Library/Logs/gym/app-app-Debug.log
```

But the problem is that this command isn't executed and after 60 minutes the CI script aborts because it takes too long. When I used the Xcode task provided by VSTS it will execute `xcodebuild` command but fail on signing. Here I have the last lines of the VSTS log:
https://pastebin.com/wZqRwmJ3

Comment: Does the build generate any log for that task? Could you share it here please? If you could add the configuration build task as well it could be usefull

Comment: It has no visible output form the task it only waits until 60 minutes expire and then it cancels the build.

Comment: @RodrigoWerlang you can find the last lines of the log here: https://pastebin.com/wZqRwmJ3

Comment: Do you use private agent? What's the result if you call that command manually on build agent machine? Is the agent running as interactive mode or the service mode with your account? If not, try it and check the result.

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT I used to use a self hosted agent but now I wanted to try to use the 'Hosted Mac OS Preview' agent. Yesterday I tried to use the provided Xcode task and this also fails. So I'm starting to think that the agent has a problem with executing xcodebuild.

Comment: What's the result if you call that command manually on build agent machine? Is the agent running as interactive mode or the service mode with your account?

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT There's no result. The only result there's is the timeout VSTS is calling after 60 minutes. And it's a hosted agent so I don't determine the mode it's running in.

Comment: Can you setup a private agent on your machine?

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT Yes I have it currently working on a private agent but it's still odd that the vsts Mac preview image doesn't run xcodebuild commands.

Comment: Do you need to interactive with it after calling the command? Such as prompt a window for confirm and you need to accept it manually?

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT No, the build should just run xcodebuild. I tried using the built-in option but that also doesn't work.  The command just stalls.

Answer (score 0):

You should add this extension to your VSTS environment to enable easier interactions with Fastlane. https://github.com/Microsoft/app-store-vsts-extension

There is extensive documentation in the README that I don't just want to copy and paste here, but basically you install the [extension from the Azure DevOps Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items/ms-vsclient.app-store), then add it as a "Deploy" step, and configure a couple "secure" environment variables to allow it to login and perform the deploy.

Comment: It's been a year ago but as far as I can remember the extension had some limitations and that's why I scripted all fastlane scripts.